# Why is typeof equaling a string in this for loop?

Tags: javascript

If I run this code in the jsFiddle it correctly seems to log the `typeof`, first six are `strings` then the seventh index is an `object`. However in my personal local code, all seven indexes are a `string`, and if you copy and paste this code into the console it logs all also as a `string`. Why is this?

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xcuje23q/

JS:

```
var someArray = ['Mike','Brett','Kim','Steve','Amy','Tanner',{name:'Oliver'}];

for(var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++){

  var name = someArray[i];
  console.log(typeof name)

}
```

Comment: Because you use {} for last, it's mean object

Comment: Yes, I know that is an object, but if you paste this code and run it in the console, all seven typeof are strings, the last should be an object not a string right?

Comment: [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is a reserved global in browsers and can only be assigned a string value. Assigning anything else automatically converts it to a string.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski This should be the real answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javascript follows function level scope, there is property `name` for window object(global) and in console, it refers to property of window as it is executed in `global context(window.name)`

Use [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)(`(function(){ /*your code */ })()`) to get expected output as `name` does not belong to `window` anymore. `function(){ }` has its own `scope`

```js
(function() {
  var someArray = ['Mike', 'Brett', 'Kim', 'Steve', 'Amy', 'Tanner', {
    name: 'Oliver'
  }];

  for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    var name = someArray[i];
    console.log(typeof name)
  }
})()
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit:** Refer [`WebKit Bugzilla`](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19967) for some interesting discussion about `window.name`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by IIFE?

Comment: @LolCoder아카쉬 [Immediately-invoked function expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript).

Comment: Oh !!! Used to stick with this practice but never acquainted with this acronym. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

There is one more alternative you may like. Do not use the `variable name`. 
Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xcuje23q/2/)

```
var someArray = ['Mike','Brett','Kim','Steve','Amy','Tanner',{name:'Oliver'}];

for(var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++){

  console.log(typeof someArray[i])
  // o/p 6 string and 1 object

}
```

OR

```
var someArray = ['Mike','Brett','Kim','Steve','Amy','Tanner',{name:'Oliver'}];

for(var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++){

  var name2 = someArray[i]; // change name of the variable.
  console.log(typeof name2)

}
```